# calculate total app cache size in android

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to calculate all cache size.my code is as follow..

```
   totalSize=0;

    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();


     /* List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
      .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);*/
     // PackageManager.GET_META_DATA

    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {

        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);

        Method getPackageSizeInfo;
        try {
            getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod(
                    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                    IPackageStatsObserver.class);

            getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                throws RemoteException {

                            totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                            Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod(
                        "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                        IPackageStatsObserver.class);

                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName,
                        new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

                            @Override
                            public void onGetStatsCompleted(
                                    PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
                                    throws RemoteException {

                                totalSize = totalSize + pStats.cacheSize;
                                Log.d("size", totalSize+"");
                                Toast.makeText(context, "size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                );
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.d("eeeeeeeeeee", "error");
                ee.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } 

    }
    Log.d("return size", totalSize+"");
    Toast.makeText(context, "return size"+totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return totalSize;
```

Here I get cache size for each package.the problem is the value of totalSize is returned first and then the function onGetStatsCompleted() called. So I always get 0 value for totalSize.

It also give Exception:-

JavaBinder(525): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
JavaBinder(525): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Guddu : instead of returning you should need to do your work inside onGetStatsCompleted method

Comment: I cant return totalSize in onStatsCompleted its inner class method

Comment: @Guddu Can you write the answer to this question ? How did u solved?

Comment: @Vivek Warde
Hi,Sorry for late reply.
by using CountDownLatch Latch and AsynchTask solved this issue.

Comment: @Guddu Then can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Toast` from your callback `onGetStatsCompleted()` method. You will get rid of the exception

Replace your code with something like this and check if it works for you.

```
private int getTotalSize() {
        totalSize = 0;

        PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

        List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            Method getPackageSizeInfo;
            try {
                getPackageSizeInfo = packageManager.getClass().getMethod("getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
                getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(packageManager, p.packageName, new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
                        totalSize = (int) (totalSize + pStats.cacheSize);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }
        }
        Log.d("return size", totalSize + "");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total cache size : " + totalSize, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return totalSize;
    }
```

Comment: no sir,this code is not working for me.My problem is method onGetStatsCompleted() call after returning total size.
I want something like..totalSize should return after finishing onGetStatsCompleted() call.

Comment: got the solution ..by using CountDownLatch Latch and AsynchTask solved the issue.

Comment: Can you guide me, what is IPackageStatsObserver and IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() classes?

Comment: i m trying to add objects in an arraylist inside onGetStatsCompleted  method and its throwing error